# For loop does not execute for given input array

Tags: c#, for-loop

I'm trying to make a program that takes in a amount of inputs, and creates an average for all of them. When I try to execute the code, the loop does not function, and the program immediately ends.

This is a picture
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VywEt.jpg

This is the code I wrote:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Practice

{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double[] inputs = new double[]{ };
            Console.WriteLine("How many numbers do you want to average?");
            double z = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if(z <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You cannot average one number. Please restart the program");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your first number. Press enter after each input. To get the final average type CALCULATE");
                for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter you next number");
                    double number = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                string response = null;
                double final = Average(inputs);
                switch (response)
                {
                    case "CALCULATE":
                        Console.WriteLine("The average of all numbers inputed is {0}", final);
                        break;
                }
            }
            

        }

        public static double Average(double[]allnumbers)
        {
            double average = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < allnumbers.Length; i++)
            {
                average += allnumbers[i];
                average /= allnumbers.Length;
            }
            return average;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your `inputs` array is empty thats why program  immediately ends.

Comment: Your Average function should divide only after all entries are summed

Answer (score 0):

Your code have few problems.

1. You are not setting anything in inputs so the program is not doing anything.
2. the response variable is not populating anywhere in the code

Look at the below code and try it, hope it helps and give you understanding too:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double[] inputs;
    Console.WriteLine("How many numbers do you want to average?");
    int z = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (z <= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You cannot average one number. Please restart the program");
    }
    else
    {
        inputs = new double[z];
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your first number. Press enter after each input. To get the final average type CALCULATE");
        for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Length; i++)
        {
            double number = -1;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter you next number");
            string response = Console.ReadLine();
            if (double.TryParse(response, out number))
            {
                inputs[i] = number;
            }
            else
            {
                switch (response)
                {
                    case "CALCULATE":
                        double final = Average(inputs);
                        Console.WriteLine("The average of all numbers inputed is {0}", final);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```